# MD5 Mismatch between Python and PHP

Tags: python, php, md5

I am trying to compare the MD5 string between PHP and Python, the server we have is working fine with PHP clients, but when we tried to do the same in python, we always get an invalid response from the server.

I have the following piece of code In Python

```
import hashlib
keyString = '96f6e3a1c4748b81e41ac58dcf6ecfa0'
decodeString = ''
length = len(keyString)
for i in range(0, length, 2):
   subString1 = keyString[i:(i + 2)]
   decodeString += chr(int(subString1, 16))
print(hashlib.md5(decodeString.encode("utf-8")).hexdigest())
```

`Produces: 5a9536a1490714cb77a02080f902be4c`

now, the same concept in PHP:

```
$serverRandom = "96f6e3a1c4748b81e41ac58dcf6ecfa0";
$length = strlen($serverRandom);
$server_rand_code = '';
for($i = 0; $i < $length; $i += 2)
  {
    $server_rand_code .= chr(hexdec(substr($serverRandom, $i, 2)));
  }
echo 'SERVER CODE: '.md5($server_rand_code).'<br/>';
```

`Produces: b761f889707191e6b96954c0da4800ee`

I tried checking the encoding, but no luck, the two MD5 output don't match at all, any help?

Comment: is this hash for passwords?

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Do you use the same input strings for the md5 call?

Comment: What is `srv_rand` and `serverRandomCode` in the python script?

Comment: edited the code, and the problem we are trying to resolve is to create a matched MD5 string across PHP and Python

Comment: Of course, they are the same string, you can see that in the code, same steps been followed to replicate the same MD5, but for some reason, this doesn't work.

Comment: Please share the input values for the md5 method

Comment: The input value contains special characters, control characters, you won't be able to tell if the strings are interpreted the same way, but according the to the documentation on both PHP and Python, they should be the same

Comment: Looking only at the final md5 result and going, "oh, they are different", doesn't tell you much. Check what `decodeString` and `$server_rand_code` contain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your method of generating the byte string is incorrect, so the input to `hashlib.md5` is wrong:

```
print(decodeString.encode('utf-8'))
# b'\xc2\x96\xc3\xb6\xc3\xa3\xc2\xa1\xc3\x84t\xc2\x8b\xc2\x81\xc3\xa4\x1a\xc3\x85\xc2\x8d\xc3\x8fn\xc3\x8f\xc2\xa0'
```

The easiest way to interpret the string as a hex string of bytes is to use [`binascii.unhexlify`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/binascii.html#binascii.unhexlify), or [`bytes.fromhex`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.fromhex):

```
import binascii

decodeString  = binascii.unhexlify(keyString)
decodeString2 = bytes.fromhex(keyString)

print(decodeString)
# b'\x96\xf6\xe3\xa1\xc4t\x8b\x81\xe4\x1a\xc5\x8d\xcfn\xcf\xa0'

print(decodeString == decodeString2)
# True
```

You can now directly use the resulting `bytes` object in `hashlib.md5`:

```
import hashlib

result = hashlib.md5(decodeString)
print(result.hexdigest())
# 'b761f889707191e6b96954c0da4800ee'
```